# Alternative to array_column function used as search

Tags: php, arrays

Search all navigation items:

```
$navitems_locations_array = array_unique(array_column($projects, 'location'));
asort($navitems_locations_array);
```

This works on my localhost but not on live. My server doesn't support it. And I'm using lower version of PHP.

And this is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()

Any alternative with the same output?

Here is my sample arrray list:

`Array( [ name ] => P1 [ description ] => Lorem Ipsum [ location ] => air city[ type ] => high rise[ status ] => new [ tags ] => [ page_url ] => project-1[ image ] => projects/images/p1/project-image.jpg[ timeline ] => )`

Comment: can you share your `print_r($projects)` in your post?

Comment: Do you have multiple arrays like this  in your `$projects` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own function `array_column` if you PHP version does not support it:

```
if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
function array_column($input = null, $columnKey = null, $indexKey = null)
{
    $argc = func_num_args();
    $params = func_get_args();

    if ($argc < 2) {
        trigger_error("array_column() expects at least 2 parameters, {$argc} given", E_USER_WARNING);
        return null;
    }

    if (!is_array($params[0])) {
        trigger_error(
            'array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, ' . gettype($params[0]) . ' given',
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return null;
    }

    if (!is_int($params[1])
        && !is_float($params[1])
        && !is_string($params[1])
        && $params[1] !== null
        && !(is_object($params[1]) && method_exists($params[1], '__toString'))
    ) {
        trigger_error('array_column(): The column key should be either a string or an integer', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($params[2])
        && !is_int($params[2])
        && !is_float($params[2])
        && !is_string($params[2])
        && !(is_object($params[2]) && method_exists($params[2], '__toString'))
    ) {
        trigger_error('array_column(): The index key should be either a string or an integer', E_USER_WARNING);
        return false;
    }

    $paramsInput = $params[0];
    $paramsColumnKey = ($params[1] !== null) ? (string) $params[1] : null;

    $paramsIndexKey = null;
    if (isset($params[2])) {
        if (is_float($params[2]) || is_int($params[2])) {
            $paramsIndexKey = (int) $params[2];
        } else {
            $paramsIndexKey = (string) $params[2];
        }
    }

    $resultArray = array();

    foreach ($paramsInput as $row) {
        $key = $value = null;
        $keySet = $valueSet = false;

        if ($paramsIndexKey !== null && array_key_exists($paramsIndexKey, $row)) {
            $keySet = true;
            $key = (string) $row[$paramsIndexKey];
        }

        if ($paramsColumnKey === null) {
            $valueSet = true;
            $value = $row;
        } elseif (is_array($row) && array_key_exists($paramsColumnKey, $row)) {
            $valueSet = true;
            $value = $row[$paramsColumnKey];
        }

        if ($valueSet) {
            if ($keySet) {
                $resultArray[$key] = $value;
            } else {
                $resultArray[] = $value;
            }
        }

    }

    return $resultArray;
}

}
```

[Reference:](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php)

Answer (score 4):

Try this hope it will help you out. Here we are using `array_map` for gathering locations.

```
$locations=array();

array_map(function($value) use (&$locations) {
    $locations[]=$value["location"];//we are gathering index location
},  $yourArray);//add your array here in place of $yourArray.

print_r(array_unique($locations));
```

Comment: @c.k Updated my post now you check. I just gave you an alternative for `array_column` rest of your code will remain same, you have to apply `array_unique` for this as well.

Comment: What is proper way to code it echoing with asort function?

Comment: I am using foreach loop to display them in navigation item.

Comment: I am now using this: $locations_array=array();
array_map(function($value) use (&$locations_array){
    $locations_array[]=$value["location"];
},  $projects);

$navitems_locations_array = (asort(array_unique($locations_array)));

Comment: For echoing:  <? foreach ($navitems_locations_array as $location) { ?>
                      <li class="subnavigation1 nav2col"><a href="/page/property/?location=<?=$location?>"><?=ucwords($location);?></a></li>
        
      <? } ?>

Answer (score 1):

It is usually useful to read *User Contributed Notes* on the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php).

For example below the [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) article, there are several variants of implementations for versions lower than PHP 5.5. Here is [the most popular one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#117229):

```
if(!function_exists("array_column"))
{

    function array_column($array,$column_name)
    {

        return array_map(function($element) use($column_name){return $element[$column_name];}, $array);

    }

}
```

But it doesn't support `$index_key`, so you can find [another one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#118831) there, which does:

```
if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column($input, $column_key, $index_key = null) {
        $arr = array_map(function($d) use ($column_key, $index_key) {
            if (!isset($d[$column_key])) {
                return null;
            }
            if ($index_key !== null) {
                return array($d[$index_key] => $d[$column_key]);
            }
            return $d[$column_key];
        }, $input);

        if ($index_key !== null) {
            $tmp = array();
            foreach ($arr as $ar) {
                $tmp[key($ar)] = current($ar);
            }
            $arr = $tmp;
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

You can find a couple more alternatives in the *User Contributed Notes*.